# MySQL IMDB Filtering Release Dates

Tags: mysql, filtering, imdb

I have asked a similar question but I was advised to ask this separately.

I'm working with the IMDB database and the release_dates table is setup like:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| movie_id     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| release_date | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)

movie_id    release_date
    2     USA:22 January 2006
    3     USA:12 February 2006
    4     USA:19 February 2006
    5     USA:22 January 2006
    6     USA:19 March 2006
```

However, there are some records that only have parts of the date:

```
movie_id    release_date
    86     USA:June 2005
    90     USA:2003
```

Which doesn't work with:

```
SELECT str_to_date(substring_index(release_date, ':', -1), '%d %M %Y') FROM release_dates;
```

because it causes the records that have only the year or month/year to come out NULL.

My ideal result would be being able to filter out movies from before 1984, I'm just not sure how to accomplish this with the unfortunately fragmented data that I have.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the records that have an incomplete date you could use regex to only return those that have a full date. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Or you could use a case statement and 
Account for the different variations in the date.

https://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html